# Form validation not working for adding images in django 1.11

Tags: django

I have an app where i am uploading multiple images and uploading it.
It works fine but without uploading anything if i click on upload it gives me an error because the validations are working. This is the error:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'gallery'"
```

This is my code here:

models.py

```
class GalleryImage(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/obituaries', db_index=True)
    obituary = models.ForeignKey(Obituary, related_name="gallery")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.obituary.name
```

Views.py

```
class GalleryAddView(View):
    def post(self, request, slug):
        try:
            data = request.FILES['gallery']
            if len(request.FILES.getlist('gallery')) > 10:
                messages.error(request, "Max gallery images limit exceeded! Only 10 images are allowed.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse('obituary:public', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
            if request.FILES['gallery']:
                for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
                    print(f)
            instance1 = Obituary.objects.get(slug=slug)

            if self.request.FILES:
                for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
                    GalleryImage.objects.create(obituary=instance1, image=f)
            messages.success(request, "Gallery images uploaded successfully!")
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Please upload some images')

        except Obituary.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, constants.OPERATION_UNSUCCESSFUL)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('obituary:public', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

forms.py

```
class GalleryForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = GalleryImage
        fields = ['image']
```

template.html

```
<form class="setting-form" id="create_obit" action="{% url 'obituary:gallery' obituary.slug %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
         {% if gallery|length > 0 %}
                 <h3>Upload More Gallery Photos</h3>
         {% else %}
                 <h3>Upload Gallery Photos</h3>
         {% endif %}
         <div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
               <div class="fallback">
                    (Maximum image size should be 8 MB)
                       <input type="file" name="gallery" class="form-control input-field" id="id_user_image" accept="image/*" multiple>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" id="create" class="btn send-btn" >Upload</button>
             </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I dont know where i am going wrong.

Comment: So, use your form in your view,form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: @minglyu see my code i have updated it, now should i directly save it inside form valid.

Comment: @AadilShaikh Can you provide traceback or at least the line where the error occurs?

Comment: @NikitinRoman It is giving me an error in data = request.FILES['gallery']. It is only giving if i dont select any image. And if i select image and post them it is successfully posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in this line:

```
data = request.FILES['gallery']
```

As you don't send files, `request.FILES` is empty and therefore raises exception on direct access.

Possible solution would be to check first is `request.FILES` has the key `'gallery'`, and don't do the checks otherwise, look at the following code:

```
 def post(self, request, slug):
        try:
            if request.FILES.get('gallery'):
                data = request.FILES['gallery']
                if len(request.FILES.getlist('gallery')) > 10:
                    messages.error(request, "Max gallery images limit exceeded! Only 10 images are allowed.")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse('obituary:public', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
                if request.FILES['gallery']:
                    for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
                        print(f)

            instance1 = Obituary.objects.get(slug=slug)
            form = GalleryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                if self.request.FILES:
                    for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
                        GalleryImage.objects.create(obituary=instance1, image=f)
                messages.success(request, "Gallery images uploaded successfully!")
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Please upload some images')

        except Obituary.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, constants.OPERATION_UNSUCCESSFUL)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('obituary:public', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

Comment: Yes you r right the error was on data. And thanks it worked.